# Reference of a phrase

Tags: reference

What the bold part reffered to? Could it be rephrased like this: "and children learn the reflex to think in terms of mental states". If yes, what's the meaning of reflex to think about mental state?

> Furthermore, we know from developmental research that children learn to think about mental states and **the reflex to think in terms of them** in the context of families where they have opportunities to learn and through relationships where they experience others as mentalizing and get help to develop these capacities themselves (Clarke-Stewart & Dunn, 2006; Denham &
>   Kochanoff, 2002a, 2002b; Symons, Fossum, & Collins, 2006; Taumoepeau & Ruffman, 2008).
>
> Midgley, N., Ensink, K., Lindqvist, K., Malberg, N., & Muller, N. (2017). Mentalization-based treatment for children: A time-limited approach. American Psychological Association.

Comment: What does your dictionary tell you about the meaning of "reflex". What do you understand by the words "mental" and "state".

Comment: @JamesK I think the sentence is a bit unusually long winded and OP is confused and wants to understand the meaning of the entire sentence, though knowing the definition of each word. I am also having hard time to understand this too long a sentence.

Comment: @Cardinal you may be right. But first I want to know what research the OP has done, how they understand the terms.  I don't think there is any particular ELL question here, in the sense that native speakers would have just as much difficulty in understanding the dense psychological text

Comment: I find the sentence to be essentially meaningless. It's too convoluted to be parsed in any understandable way. I could likely answer the *specific* question about the phrase—but I would fail to answer what the phrase means in the context of the overall sentence, which is the real question. I have no idea what the sentence is saying. (It almost has a science fiction vibe to it.) I do note that the final word of the sentence (if it is the final word) is cut off. But I can't see how knowing it (or anything that comes after it) could help.

Comment: @JasonBassford The sentence is complicated but the question asks about a specific part, with two "trick" in a row. Actually, after *in terms of them*, I find the sentence only hard to understand semantically, not grammatically.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't quite rephrase it as you suggest. It's a poorly-written and confusing sentence but what it's saying is:

*Furthermore, we know from developmental research that children (1) learn to think about mental states and (2)* [learn] *the reflex to think in terms of them* [the mental states] *in the context*...

Comment: thanks.
 ...and (2) [learn] **to reflect thinking** in terms of them [the mental states] in the context. 
Is it the same as you said?